# How to use redux-orm with redux and redux-toolkit

Tags: react-redux, redux-orm

It's so funny that I'm using redux-orm but found it's hard to work with react-redux (though it's called redux-orm) on my end.

I got **TypeError: Cannot read property 'Article' of undefined** by using your method.

Let me sidetrack this question a little bit.

Is there any more popular ORM library than redux-orm, it's only has few examples on the internet.

## Article.js

````
```
class Article extends Model {
    static reducer(action, Article, session) {
        switch (action.type) {
            case 'load_all':
                action.payload.forEach(articleData=>{
                    Article.create(articleData);
                })
                return session;
                break;
        }
        return undefined;
    } 
}

Article.modelName = 'Article'
Article.fields = {
        id: attr(), // non-relational field for any value; optional but highly recommended
        name: attr(),
};

export default Article;

```
````

## orm.js

```
    const orm = new ORM ({
      stateSelector: state => state.orm,
    });
    orm.register(Article);
```

## ArticleList.js

```
    const articlesSelector = createSelector(orm.Article);
    const ormArticles = useSelector(state => articlesSelector(state, null));
```